# Joining 2 tables to pull all values from each

Tags: sql, join

I've got 2 tables that i'm wanting to join in a specific way to retrieve all the data in each even though some of the joined fields may not exist in each, sort of like a full outer join.

Table A

```
+--------+-------+------+-------+
| Group  | Name  | Year | Value |
+--------+-------+------+-------+
|      1 | Joe   | 2018 |    23 |
|      1 | Joe   | 2019 |    56 |
|      2 | Fred  | 2019 |    89 |
|      2 | Fred  | 2020 |    45 |
+--------+-------+------+-------+
```

Table B

```
+-------+------+------+-------+----------+
| Group | Name | Year | Scope |  Status  |
+-------+------+------+-------+----------+
|     1 | Joe  | 2019 |    78 | Approved |
|     2 | Fred | 2018 |    12 | Approved |
|     2 | Fred | 2020 |   987 | Started  |
|     2 | Fred | 2021 |   321 | Sent     |
+-------+------+------+-------+----------+
```

I want to join on A.Group = B.Group and A.Year = B.Year, but when year exists on one and not the other then show a null on the other side. So there will be a row for every name for every year and corresponding values or 0/null depending on what is available. So the result for this example should look like this:

Table A and B

```
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+----------+
| A.Group | A.Name | A.Year | A.Value | B.Group | B.Name | B.Year | B.Scope | B.Status |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+----------+
|       1 | Joe    |   2018 |      23 |       1 | Joe    |   2018 |       0 | <null>   |
|       1 | Joe    |   2019 |      56 |       1 | Joe    |   2019 |      78 | Approved |
|       1 | Joe    |   2020 |       0 |       1 | Joe    |   2020 |       0 | <null>   |
|       1 | Joe    |   2021 |       0 |       1 | Joe    |   2021 |       0 | <null>   |
|       2 | Fred   |   2018 |       0 |       2 | Fred   |   2018 |      12 | Approved |
|       2 | Fred   |   2019 |      89 |       2 | Fred   |   2019 |       0 | <null>   |
|       2 | Fred   |   2020 |      45 |       2 | Fred   |   2020 |     987 | Started  |
|       2 | Fred   |   2021 |       0 |       2 | Fred   |   2021 |     321 | Sent     |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: [mre] please. (Including DBMS.) What are you able to do? Do you know what an outer join is? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Your description of what you want is not clear. It's not helpful to say that you want something like a join. You can't expect to be able to code a solution if you can't clearly state what the condition is for a row of values to be in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database support CTE, you can use CTE. Other case you can use SUB QUERY to replace CTE by taking help from the below logic to achieve your desired output

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e81b8c747571804a99a1d8a798feae9d)

```
WITH CTE_Group([Group],Name)
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Group],Name FROM tab_A
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT [Group],Name FROM tab_B
),
CTE_Year(Year)
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM tab_A
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM tab_B
)
SELECT A.[Group],A.Name,B.Year,ISNULL(C.Value,0) Value,
A.[Group],A.Name,B.Year,ISNULL(D.Scope,0) Scope,D.Status
FROM CTE_Group A
CROSS APPLY CTE_Year B
LEFT JOIN Tab_A C ON A.[Group] = C.[Group] AND B.Year = C.Year
LEFT JOIN Tab_B D ON A.[Group] = D.[Group] AND B.Year = D.Year
ORDER BY 1,3
```

Output-

```
Group   Name    Year    Value   Group   Name    Year    Scope   Status
1       Joe     2018    23      1       Joe     2018    0   
1       Joe     2019    56      1       Joe     2019    78      Approved
1       Joe     2020    0       1       Joe     2020    0   
1       Joe     2021    0       1       Joe     2021    0   
2       Fred    2018    0       2       Fred    2018    12      Approved
2       Fred    2019    89      2       Fred    2019    0   
2       Fred    2020    45      2       Fred    2020    987     Started
2       Fred    2021    0       2       Fred    2021    321     Sent
```

Comment: Fantastic, that does it. Can see it also caters for the cases where a Name may not have a year in either table, and will still list a row for them regardless with 0/null. And also picks up any additional years added to do the same. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome @David_S53. Nice to hear that it helped :) Please don't forget to put an up vote as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right David, this should be what you wnat.
Let me know

```
Select
A.Group, A.Name, A.Year, coalesce(A.Value,0) as A.Value, B.Group, B.Name, B.Year, B.Scope, B.Status
From TableA A cross join TableB B on A.Group = B.Group and A.Year = B.Year
```